# I own 35% of a family business. I resigned from the company but still own 35%, should I be receiving 35% of the profits of the company?

Tags: shares

I own 35% of a family business. I resigned from the company but still own 35%, should I be receiving 35% of the profits of the company? What are my legal rights to this company as they have refused to buy me out right now.

Comment: I suspect there is no simple answer to this question.  What country are you in?  How is the company constituted?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requests information on legal rights, and should be posted on law.stackexchange.com

Comment: And what class are the shares, and how much if the profit is being invested in growing the business, and...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How is the business organized? If as a General Partnership or LLC that reports as a partnership, you will be getting distributed to you each year your % ownership of the earnings or loss. But note, this is a paperwork transfer on the form K-1, which must then carryover to your tax return, it does not require the transfer of cash to you.

If organized as an S-Corp, you should be holding shares of the company that you may sell back to the S-Corp, generally as outlined in the original articles of incorporation. The annual 'dividend' (earnings remaining after all expenses are paid) should be distributed to you in proportion to the shares you hold.

If a C-Corp and there is only one class of stock that you also hold a percentage of, the only 'profits' that must be distributed proportionally to you are declared dividends by the board of directors.

Most family run business are loosely formed with not much attention paid to the details of partnership agreements or articles of incorporation, and so don't handle family ownership disputes very well. From my experience, trying to find an amicable settlement is the best...and least expensive....approach to separation from the business. But if this can't be done or there is a sizable value to the business, you may have to get your own legal counsel.

Comment: This answer assumes the OP is in the US, which is not stated or implied anywhere I can see. Also, a more direct answer requires much more information from the OP.

Comment: The company is in the US and is incorporated

Comment: Partnerships generally specify a profit/loss sharing ratio in the partnership agreement, so the person may not necessarily be entitled to 35% of the profit if the company is a partnership.